# Preserving GIt History after file move to other directory

Tags: git, github

We are working on git repo where i made couple of commits, then one of other contributor moved those files to some other directory and the commit history before the move is disappeared for those perticular files from the github's file history button section, it show commits after the move only, I was trying to find way to figure out how to add previous commit history for those moved files. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That’s odd. Can you share the commit tree?

Comment: It is private repo, I am not allowed to share it

Comment: But in the GIt log those commits are there

Comment: Could you then share a dummy version which represents it?